# Read email data from outlook into a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, outlook, office-automation

I am trying to read emails from an outlook mailbox and organize them into a Pandas dataframe. So far, I'm able to make the connection and pull the subjects but when I try to add it into the dataframe it doesn't seem to work.

Approach so far- this connects me to the mailbox:

```
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.Folders('user@mail.com').Folders('Inbox')
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['business_date_integer', 'sender', 'subject', 'body', 'attachment'])

subject_list = []

for message in messages:
    subject_list.append(message.Subject)
```

When I try to append the subject to the list, it appends each subject as a list. I imagine this is an inefficient way to solve this problem. My goal is to have a final dataframe that looks like this:

```
business_date_integer  sender         subject     body        attachment
20220504               bob@gmail.com  RE:Hello    test_email  True
```

Answer (score 0):

For adding information into dataframes, you want to stick with simple datatypes (i.e. bool, strings, integers, etc).
You're trying to add an object, so what I would do is convert that `message.subject` to a string, and put that into the dataframe instead.

Try this:

```
for message in messages:
    subject_list.append(str(message.Subject))
```

Thanks!
-VikingOfValhalla

Comment: thanks for this- i still can't seem to add the subject string to a dataframe- i seem to be getting ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (0,1)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no need to get the inbox folder twice in the code:

```
inbox = outlook.Folders('user@mail.com').Folders('Inbox')
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
```

The [GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getdefaultfolder) method of the `Namespace` class returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder of the requested type for the current profile; for example, obtains the default Inbox folder for the user who is currently logged on.

It seems you need to extract the required fields in the data frame from the messages in the loop. Note, you need to operate with primitive data types.